# Logback/Groovy is throwing a URL ClassCastException when trying to evaluate url.text

Tags: groovy, logback, logback-groovy

I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.net.URL cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$948.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)>
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$Proxy.doMethodInvoke(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:70)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:73)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:61)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferConfigurator.run(GafferConfigurator.groovy:44)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferUtil.runGafferConfiguratorOn(GafferUtil.java:43)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:66)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:142)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:121)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:332)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:284)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5162)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

when trying to start Tomcat 8 using Logback 1.1.2 and Groovy 2.3.6/Java 8. The URL for the `logback.groovy` file is coming from a shared jar and looks correct when debugging:
`jar:file:/Users/matt.whipple/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.example/core/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/c30ff0f9caae010d728248c66cc55f40bf591232/core-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/logback.groovy`

The issue seems to be with the call to `url.text` in the GDK. It appears as though this is an issue with this version of Groovy. If in the debugger I try alternate methods to fetch the contents of the URL I get similar `ClassCastException`s, but updating to Groovy 2.4.1 resolves the issue.

Comment: Looks like something isn't calling `url.text` and is just passing the url?

Comment: `url.text` is being called as part of: https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/groovy/ch/qos/logback/classic/gaffer/GafferConfigurator.groovy which is where the error is being thrown.  Setting a breakpoint there and doing alternate approaches like url.openStream.text or url.openStream.eachLine{...} also throw ClassCastExceptions.  I'm guessing the Groovy typing system is getting waylaid somewhere.